# Fixed height container with scrolling that resizes based on the window height

Tags: html, css, sass

I have an Angular Material table where I want the header and footer to be sticky and the content to scroll.  To do this I simply need to put the table in a container, set the height to a certain amount of pixels, then set the overflow to auto.  This works as intended.  I just need something like this to work for multiple resolutions.  If I set my div to 600px it looks great on my computer but someone else would see a double scroll bar.

As mentioned if I set the height to a fixed amount of pixels that works great (eg: height: 600px).  I've tried using the calc function(eg: height: calc(100%-200px)) but that doesn't seem to work, the table just takes up all the room.

I have done a bunch of media queries at 10px intervals and set the fixed height in each one.  This works but seems like a terrible solution.

I feel like there has to be a way to set a fixed container to have a height that is the screen height minus a certain amount of pixels (to account for the header and some white space at the bottom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `vh` rather then `%`

```
height: calc(100vh-200px)
```

Comment: That works!!!, not sure why I couldn't find this in Google, so simple. I'm guessing if I wanted to do width I would use hh.  I'm assuming vh stands for vertical height so width would be defined by horizontal height.

Comment: hahah! just like `vh`  there is `vw` as well You can also explore it

Comment: @Zoey `vh` stands for viewport height, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length for more details. `1vh` is 1% of the viewport height.